# HTML CSS Table, fixed and autoajust

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need some help with table, I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <td>Content</td>
        <th>Title</th>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want my `th` to be both fixed, so let say `200px`, and I want my content to be auto-adjust but to have both the same size, the content on my `td` is dynamic so I don't know if there will be a lot of content or nothing, I just want the `td` to fill the space available and share that space. so if there is `600px` available, I want my `td` to be `300px`.
Is that possible?

Comment: you shouldn't mix th and td cells in the same row, this is not a good practice. I think there are articles about this. But I don't think that makes the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your table a fixed [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) and it will do exactly this. Your `th` elements will be 200px wide and your `td` elements will be forced to fill the remaining space. If your table was 1000px wide, your two `td` elements would automatically size to 300px each.

```css
table {
    width:1000px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

th {
    width:200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/Wgsgn/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what I'm looking for, but why it doesn't work with that: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgsgn/2/

Comment: @Mokkun that looks fine to me. Remember that you've set your table to use 100% width. If you look at the embedded result you'll see that the `th` elements are fixed at 200px and the `td` elements expand: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgsgn/2/embedded/result/

Comment: It's not fine since the th doesn't stay at 200px, they also expand..., try to resize the page you'll see the th resize also

Comment: @Mokkun strange, removing the fixed `table-layout` altogether fixes that. I'll change my answer.

Comment: it still doesn't work, now the content doesn't have the same size if one is bigger than the other http://jsfiddle.net/Wgsgn/3/

Comment: @Mokkun it seems to be the top `th` which is causing this issue. I have no idea why this would happen, but removing the top `th` fixes the widths using `table-layout:fixed`.